# How can i receive information of a media being played in the media player and YouTube app (Android phone)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer, youtube-data-api

i wanted to know how can i receive information about the current audio or video being played in the media player or the YouTube app in a android phone using broadcast receiver?

Information: 
1. Audio/Video Details 
2. Seek time (i.e where the track currently is)
3. Media ID or location of media in memory